# Change Unknown Variable Values With Tkinter Buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can we change value of a variable if a Tkinter button is clicked and close the window

What I tried is:

```
import tkinter

m = tkinter.Tk()
lis = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'] # values can be anything

def change_value(val):
    global var
    var = val

var = ''

for i, j in enumerate(lis):
    b = tkinter.Button(m, text=j, command=change_value(j))
    b.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

I have no idea where to use m.destroy() and how to print var.
And this also changes the var without clicking the button.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the window to close after the variable's been assigned, put m.destroy() at the end of the change_value() function.

The reason your variable changes before the button is pressed is because you need to wrap your command in a lambda statement ie.

```
Button(... command=lambda x=j: change_value(x) )
```

Also, make sure you call mainloop on your window, 'm', not the tkinter module ie.

```
m.mainloop()
```

Once your button has been pressed and m.destroy() has been called in your change_value function, mainloop ends and you can do what you like with your variable.